# A function created by Integrate which can be plotted only with certain argument names; NIntegrate works better, but

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

Here's the  function:

```
ps = Exp[-#] &;
int[s_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := (s (z - s + Log[s]))^(-1);
j[z_?NumericQ] := Integrate[int[x, z], {x, ps[z], z}];
Plot[Evaluate[j[z]], {z, 1/3, 1/2}]
```

Evaluating does not work

```
j[.5]
```

Plotting three more times with different argument names leads to  two failures and a success on Version 11.3 (it seems to work only with an argument which has not been used before)

```
Plot[Evaluate[j[x]], {x, 1/3, 1/2}]
Plot[Evaluate[j[s]], {s, 1/3, 1/2}]
Plot[Evaluate[j[y]], {y, 1/3, 1/2}]
```

Comment: This is an issue coming from using `Integrate` when you wanted `NIntegrate`. The former tries to do symbolic integration and can sometimes fallback to numerical stuff. Using `NIntegrate` fixes your issue. As is, for me, when I use the version with `Integrate` I only run into issues when using the `x` version. The issue there is that `x` in the symbolic integral gets replaced by a numerical value and Mathematica thinks there are no variables over which to integrate.

Comment: You can see that `Integrate` replaces the integration variable x with a numerical value by specifying: j[z_?NumericQ] := (Print[{z, ps[z]}];  Integrate[int[x, z], {x, ps[z], z}]);  I would call this a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues: (1) `j[]` depends on a global variable `x`, which makes it vulnerable to `x` having a numeric value instead of being a symbol; (2) `Integrate` is an exact solver, which means it won't evaluate to a number it cannot compute exactly.

The first issue is solved by localizing the variable `x` (e.g. `Module[{x},...]`).

The second issue can be solved by using `N[]` when appropriate, which I show; or by being satisfied with an approximation by `NIntegrate`, which @m_goldberg shows in his answer.

```
ps = Exp[-#] &;
int[s_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := (s (z - s + Log[s]))^(-1);
j[z_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{x}, N[Integrate[int[x, z], {x, ps[z], z}], Precision[z]]];
Plot[Evaluate[j[z]], {z, 1/3, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Michael E2.  I had not realized  that x in "Integrate[int[x, z]"  is a global variable in need to be encapsulated.  An important lesson :)   Now for "N[Integrate[int[x, z], {x, ps[z], z}], Precision[z]]]" , is this equivalent to NIntegrate?

Comment: @florin No, `N[Integrate[..], prec]` is not exactly equivalent to `NIntegrate`, although it will use `NIntegrate`. It will attempt to return a result that is accurate to `prec` digits. For example, ``z1 = 2`50/5; j[z1]`` aims to have at least 50 digits because `Precision[z1]` is `50`. `N[]` does this (as I understand it) by adapting the precision of `NIntegrate` to achieve the goal indicated by `prec`. (The docs say "attempt," so it might fail to achieve the goal in troublesome cases.) Use `NIntegrate` as in the other answers if speed and only moderate accuracy are needed.

Comment: I chose `N[Integrate[..]]` to show an alternative to `NIntegrate`, since only `NIntegrate` is shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[NIntegrate[x/(z - x + Log[x]), {x, Exp[-z], z}]], {z, 
   1/3, 1/2}] // Quiet
```

with the effect of

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I think you have the integrand wrong. I think it should be `1/x/(z - x + Log[x])`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `NItegrate` in place of `Itegrate` seems to work.

```
ps = Exp[-#] &;
int[s_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 1/(s (z - s + Log[s]))
j[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[int[x, z], {x, ps[z], z}]
Plot[j[x], {x, 1/3, 1/2}]
```

[image: plot]